# Android application paused on Marshmallow and higher

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have built an android game and published it. It works fine in Unity editor and Blue Stack emulator, and also works fine in jelly bean 4.1 on a real device.

The problem is that in Android Nougat and Marshmallow the game starts normally, the main menu appears and menus work normally. But whenever the user opens the first level, the game enters something like a paused state - the player does not move, controls do not work and even the traffic is stopped (it is a racing game). However, the pause menu can be opened using back button works fine and the user can use it normally.

This problem do not appear in Jelly Bean.

- I am using unity 5.6.2f1 personal (64bit).
- using google admob and iap.
- I have android sdk build tool 27.0.3

**NOTE1:** I confirmed that Start() function runs fine on start of scene. but update() function do not run. all update functions of all scripts are stopped. i am not changing scaled time at all.

**NOTE2:** It only happens on android marshmallow and higher.Everything works fine on lower devices.

Comment: What is your target level API ?? and Android Build tool version ?? did you check using consol in mobile ?? is there any Error ??

Comment: @Hardik in unity my target api level is selected as : Automatic (highest installed) and in drop down highest of them is android nougat 7.1 (api 25). while as i mentioned, android sdk build tool is 27.0.3. morever i  don't have android marshmallow. it is reported by many users.

Comment: @Hardik in sdk manager under Tools android sdk build tool 27.0.3 is installed. but under tools (preview channel) nothing is installed!

Comment: @Hardik here is link to pic of sdk manager. and thanks in advance.  https://answers.unity.com/storage/attachments/112855-capture.png

Comment: Sorry for late response, did You try to get an error from a console or do you have any error log  ?? because I didn't face this kind of problem, I am using AdMob latest version with Nougat and Orio.

Comment: basically i don't have any device running on marshmallow. therefore, i can not debug it. morever only game do not works. menus work great.Also application do not crashes rather it is paused. start() works but update() do not works.